# Please summarize how to implement node base licensing

Tags: licensing

Currently a user makes a purchase and then a license is generated and sent to that user, but the license isn't tied to a physical computer so there is nothing to prevent the user sharing the license with someone.

I heard people talk about creating a license tied to the mac address of the computer, so the license only works on that computer. Now I know how to get the mac address in code but I dont understand how I can do this step when they first make the purchase on the web, so please what is the basic algorithm for node locked licenses ?

Comment: So I have to call you every time I upgrade my *network card*!  Remind me to never buy your software.  Never mind that you can change a registry setting on Windows and have it think your MAC address is whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Calm down ! I dont use node based licensing at the moment I just want to know how it works, I got the impression it could be completely automated.

Answer (score 2):

Users will hate you. If you're in a niche market, build trust not barriers between you and your clients.

The reason I say this, is that I use a $20,000 per license software on my pc, and trust me, if my pc farts, the license is void and I have to call them up to reactivate.

The best control and friendliest method I find is by giving each licensed version a usb dongle. that way you can install the software on a gazillion computers but it could only run with a dongle.

Comment: A Dongle is a very expensive way to do things, and requires snail mail further adding to costs and delay and forcing the customer to provide their address details.

Comment: Agreed, my company does this as well using network and individual dongles and in my opinion much nicer for the user because they can just vpn in and use the network license if they are on the road

Comment: @user294896 IF snail mail is an issue, have the software work for 10 or 20 days (enough time for the dongle to get there)

Comment: There is also cost, Im talking about low cost ($10) software

Comment: @user294896 if it's that cheap, don't bother even putting a license on it or check winzip's system

Comment: Total sales do generate reasoanble revenue but the Cheap price and relaxed licensing policy I currently have do not deter piracy sufficiently

Comment: Winzips policy is to start slower and slower until you buy a license but my point is without any kind of node mechanism somebody can just purchase once then distribute a fully licensed app to other pirates.